# how to find coinbase secret key on the dashboard?

Tags: coinbase-api

On the API console, I only see the API key for self-use. But the most of the documentation makes a reference to a secret key either while forming the CB-ACCESS-SIGN or initializing an auth object.

Should I instead create an OAuth application even if it's for self-use? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found out that Coinbase only shows you the secret once during the key creation. If you don't save it, then you would have to delete the existing one and recreate it, which is what I did to solve this issue.